# SQL query to sum category by category with 2 column and than max value for each category for segment name

Tags: sql, sqlite

Table is look like this

```
seg_name    category    revenue
INFREQUENT  Accessoires 15
INFREQUENT  Accessoires 2
INFREQUENT  Make up     9
INFREQUENT  Make up     33
INFREQUENT  Man         8
INFREQUENT  Man         94
INFREQUENT  Women       32
INFREQUENT  Women       23
Loyal       Accessoires 72
Loyal       Accessoires 13
Loyal       Make up     18
Loyal       Make up     62
Loyal       Man         24
Loyal       Man         87
Loyal       Women       92
Loyal       Women       32
Loyal       sun         33
Loyal       sun         42
New         Accessoires 13
New         Accessoires 25
New         Make up     45
New         Make up     42
New         Man         14
New         Man         52
New         Women       32
New         Women       23
New         sun         54
New         sun         31
```

I want a query so that I can get Table like this

```
seg_name    category    revenue
INFREQUENT  Accessoires 17
INFREQUENT  Make up     42
INFREQUENT  Man         102
INFREQUENT  Women       55
Loyal       Accessoires 85
Loyal       Make up     80
Loyal       Man         111
Loyal       Women       124
Loyal       sun         75
New         Accessoires 38
New         Make up     87
New         Man         66
New         Women       55
New         sun         85
```

After That want max revenue of category in all seg_name

```
seg_name    category    revenue
INFREQUENT  Man         102
Loyal       Women       124
New         Make up     87
```

Answer (score 1):

Ue `group by` with window functions:

```
select sc.*
from (select seg_name, category, sum(revenue) as total_revenue,
             row_number() over (partition by seg_name order by sum(revenue) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by seg_name, category
     ) sc
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

With `MAX()` and `FIRST_VALUE()` window functions:

```
select distinct seg_name, 
  first_value(category) over (partition by seg_name order by sum(revenue) desc) category,
  max(sum(revenue)) over (partition by seg_name) revenue
from tablename
group by seg_name, category
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jt9ceY6H5TkZm5aB784ks9/0).
Results:

```
| seg_name   | category | revenue |
| ---------- | -------- | ------- |
| INFREQUENT | Man      | 102     |
| Loyal      | Women    | 124     |
| New        | Make up  | 87      |
```